# What are the most common ways to enable keyboards to type Pali characters in 2021?

Tags: pali-canon, pali-language, pali

Given the wide variety of possible solutions from keyboard firmware to operating system specific solutions, I'd like to leave the question wide open in order to discover which solutions are actually most commonly used by people who have this need in 2021.

I am personally most interested in solutions that work for the macOS and Linux operating systems.
Although iOS and Android solutions are also of interest to me.

Comment: Seems like more of a technical computer-based question. Maybe this would interest you: [Typing of Pali Language in Ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265501/typing-of-pali-language-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Comment: @ruben2020: sīlabbata-parāmāsa: 3rd of the 10 fetters: "unskillful attachment to rules". The stack exchange community with the greatest concentration of people (1) who can answer this question (2) will find the answers to be valuable, is this community. Rules should be changed or enforced with leniency.

Comment: Reopened based on [this meta-topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2618/254).

Comment: @ChrisW: Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please try: [fsnow Pali keyboard](http://fsnow.com/pali/keyboard/) which works on Windows.

Pali is usually rendered in Roman/ Latin characters with diacritical marks - the same ones used by Sanskrit. Pali doesn't have its own script. However, I think it's possible to render Pali also in the Sinhala script and the Devanagari script (used by Sanskrit). Hence, you can also use keyboards that render Roman/ Latin characters with Sanskrit diacritical marks, Sinhala script and Devanagari script.

Answer (score 3):

There are some topics with answers on `discourse.suttacentral.net`

- [Pali keyboard on mac os x](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/pali-keyboard-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/4558)
- [Insert Pali and Sanskrit Characters with diacritical marks](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/insert-pali-and-sanskrit-characters-with-diacritical-marks-on-discourse-and-operating-systems/311)